# Git commands to uncommit, un stage changes and remove the changes

Tags: git, github

I checkout between multiple local repo, since I work on multiple projects. Before every check out I need to commit, which means I'm unable to keep my last commit msg same as that on git cloud repo. I need some help.

Git commands :

1. revert or uncommit last changes but keep in staged area
2. Move changes from staged to unstaged area
3. Delete/remove unstaged changes

Comment: Please don't say "changes". Commits are not changes. Git traffics in commits, not changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the point,
commands for you:

1. git reset --soft HEAD~1
2. git reset
3. git checkout .